# Create great circle in openlayers 5

Tags: openlayers-5

I need to create a circle with an X radius, in meters, accounting for the curvature of the Earth.
Back in OpenLayers 2, we had `destinationVincenty`, which helped to calculate the destination from a point, taking into account the angle.
However, this seems to be missing in OpenLayers 5.

I have tested the `Cricle` geometry, but it is way too imprecise (check image).

How would go about doing this in OpenLayers 5?

[image: The blue circle was drawn with 245km radius, but the actual 245km radius should go until about the red line near Sedalia.]

The blue circle was drawn with 245km radius, but the actual 245km radius should go until about the red line near Sedalia.

Comment: Your main problem is that web mercantor scale is only true on the equator and your the radius doesn't take account of the changing scale of the projection as you move away from the equator.  For a 245km radius elsewhere in the world the radius on the map needs to be `245000/ol.proj.getPointResolution(projection,1,circleCenter) ` It will still be slightly inaccurate (go too far south and not far enough north) but will be good enough for most purposes.

Comment: Yeah, that helps, but it is still much, much more inaccurate than the open layers 2 destinationVincenty. I have no idea why they removed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the destinationVincenty function it's easy to copy from the OL2 source.
I've added the 3 obvious dependencies and changed the input lonlat and return value to OL3/4/5 type coordinate arrays, but haven't tested anything.

```
destinationVincenty = function(lonlat, brng, dist) {
    //var u = OpenLayers.Util;
    var u = {};
    u.rad = function(x) {return x*Math.PI/180;};
    u.deg = function(x) {return x*180/Math.PI;};
    u.VincentyConstants = {
        a: 6378137,
        b: 6356752.3142,
        f: 1/298.257223563
    };

    var ct = u.VincentyConstants;
    var a = ct.a, b = ct.b, f = ct.f;

    var lon1 = lonlat[0]; //lonlat.lon;
    var lat1 = lonlat[1]; //lonlat.lat;

    var s = dist;
    var alpha1 = u.rad(brng);
    var sinAlpha1 = Math.sin(alpha1);
    var cosAlpha1 = Math.cos(alpha1);

    var tanU1 = (1-f) * Math.tan(u.rad(lat1));
    var cosU1 = 1 / Math.sqrt((1 + tanU1*tanU1)), sinU1 = tanU1*cosU1;
    var sigma1 = Math.atan2(tanU1, cosAlpha1);
    var sinAlpha = cosU1 * sinAlpha1;
    var cosSqAlpha = 1 - sinAlpha*sinAlpha;
    var uSq = cosSqAlpha * (a*a - b*b) / (b*b);
    var A = 1 + uSq/16384*(4096+uSq*(-768+uSq*(320-175*uSq)));
    var B = uSq/1024 * (256+uSq*(-128+uSq*(74-47*uSq)));

    var sigma = s / (b*A), sigmaP = 2*Math.PI;
    while (Math.abs(sigma-sigmaP) > 1e-12) {
        var cos2SigmaM = Math.cos(2*sigma1 + sigma);
        var sinSigma = Math.sin(sigma);
        var cosSigma = Math.cos(sigma);
        var deltaSigma = B*sinSigma*(cos2SigmaM+B/4*(cosSigma*(-1+2*cos2SigmaM*cos2SigmaM)-
            B/6*cos2SigmaM*(-3+4*sinSigma*sinSigma)*(-3+4*cos2SigmaM*cos2SigmaM)));
        sigmaP = sigma;
        sigma = s / (b*A) + deltaSigma;
    }

    var tmp = sinU1*sinSigma - cosU1*cosSigma*cosAlpha1;
    var lat2 = Math.atan2(sinU1*cosSigma + cosU1*sinSigma*cosAlpha1,
        (1-f)*Math.sqrt(sinAlpha*sinAlpha + tmp*tmp));
    var lambda = Math.atan2(sinSigma*sinAlpha1, cosU1*cosSigma - sinU1*sinSigma*cosAlpha1);
    var C = f/16*cosSqAlpha*(4+f*(4-3*cosSqAlpha));
    var L = lambda - (1-C) * f * sinAlpha *
        (sigma + C*sinSigma*(cos2SigmaM+C*cosSigma*(-1+2*cos2SigmaM*cos2SigmaM)));

    var revAz = Math.atan2(sinAlpha, -tmp);  // final bearing

    //return new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon1+u.deg(L), u.deg(lat2));
    return [lon1+u.deg(L), u.deg(lat2)];
};
```

The nearest method available is OL3/4/5 is ol.geom.Polygon.circular()

Comment: Well, I did precisely that, but I was hoping there was a built-in way to do it on OL5 because I could not believe they would just remove something that useful and not provide another way to do it, hence my post. Imma accept your answer for your time.

Comment: There's no public destinationVincenty method but I had overlooked ol.geom.Polygon.circular() which will produce an approximation to a great circle (using sphere instead of ellipse).  Better than plain circle but still not as good as OL2.